# Why Stream.reduce() javadoc calls initial value Identity?

Tags: javascript, java, java-stream, lodash, reduce

I was always a bit confused with the [JavaDoc of reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)). It calls the initial value `Identity`.

When I read [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#reduce) documentation I get even more confused:

It seems like the **terms are reversed**. The identity is not the initial value but the function to be invoked per iteration. And the accumulator is the initial value:

> **collection (Array|Object):** The collection to iterate over.
> **[iteratee=_.identity] (Function):** The function invoked per iteration.
> **[accumulator] (*):** The initial value.

The documentation of JavaScript's [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) seems simpler. It calls the initial value: `initialValue`.

Is there a reason why the initialValue is called `Identity` and why Lodash `reduce()` and Java `reduce()` have this naming conflict?

Comment: The terminology is fine. It refers to the [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element).

Comment: About the Lodash docs: No, the function is not called 'identity', it's called 'iteratee'. There is a default value for the 'iteratee' function, which is the identity function (a function that just returns whatever is passed to it).

Comment: @Jesper Indeed I did not notice this. I still have a dark point though. In lodash the initial value is called accumulator. Is there a reason for this? In java accumulator is the function to be called for each element.

Comment: @MarinosAn accumulator is the name for what you transfer between the operations. You *accumulate* the result one step at a time. Java uses that name for the bifunction that is also the operation. Lodash uses the name for the result of applying the function - the thing you carry over. Neither of them are really wrong - in both cases it's related to continuing the operation and carrying over to the next one. The bifunction is also some times called a *reductor* or *reducer*.

Answer (score 7):

`Array.prototype.reduce()` does not support parallel processing, so the value is truly a single *initial value*.

Java's `Stream.reduce()` supports parallel processing, so the value might be used multiple times, as an initial value in each thread, and must therefore be *neutral*, like adding 0 or multiplying 1. Such a neutral value is called an *identity value*.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) says it:

> In mathematics, an **identity element**, or **neutral element**, is a special type of element of a set with respect to a binary operation on that set, which leaves any element of the set unchanged when combined with it. This concept is used in algebraic structures such as groups and rings. The term *identity element* is often shortened to *identity* (as in the case of additive identity and multiplicative identity), when there is no possibility of confusion, but the identity implicitly depends on the binary operation it is associated with.